# Fatal error: glibc detected an invalid stdio handle - file handling

Tags: c, file-handling

I am trying to use ftell in this file handling problem, but it is giving "Fatal error: glibc detected an invalid stdio handle".

Question:
Write a program to implement all the file handling functions.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{

    FILE *fptr;
    //Writing-fprintf
    fptr=fopen("File1.txt","w");
    //Text entered into file is Helloworld
    fprintf(fptr,"HelloWorld\n");
    printf("Text entered into fie1.txt is 'HelloWorld' \n");
    fclose(fptr);
    //Reading-fscanf
    fptr=fopen("File1.txt","r");
    char string[255];
    printf("Text read from file is : ");
    fscanf(fptr,"%s",string);
    printf("%s\n",string);
    fclose(fptr);
    //fseek
    fptr=fopen("File1.txt","r");
    char ch=fgetc(fptr);
    printf("Original Positionof pointer shows : ");
    printf("%c\n",ch);
    fseek(fptr, 3, SEEK_SET);
    ch=fgetc(fptr);
    printf("Position of pointer after moving 3 spaces %c\n",ch);
    //Telling current position
    printf("Current location of pointer is %ld ",ftell(fptr));
    fclose(fptr);
    char c='!';
    //Opening file in append mode for appending a character
    fptr=fopen("File1.txt","a");
    fputc( (int) c,fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
    //Opening file in read mode for appending character by character
    fptr=fopen("File1.txt","r");
    fseek(fptr,0,SEEK_SET);
    c=fgetc(fptr);
    while (c!=EOF)
    {
        printf("%c",c);
        fptr++;
        c=fgetc(fptr);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Output that I am getting:

[image: Fatal error: glibc detected an invalid stdio handle, aborted]

Can someone please tell me what my mistake is?

Comment: Whenever you use `fopen` you must check the returned pointer before using it or trying to close it.

Comment: Try replacing any "printf(...)" with "fprintf(stderr, ...)". This will cause every print statement to immediately print to the screen. Normally printf buffers output, but using this method will help you find exactly where the problem is occurring.

Comment: `fptr++` is just wrong.  Remove it, and also add `return 0` so exit code is defined, and things should be okay.